# Upgrading STM32L1 firmware takes a long time

Tags: stm32, flash, bootloader

I have a **STM32L152R8T6-A** MCU. A new firmware is downloaded over HTTP (as a .bin file) and is stored in an external flash memory. After that a bootloader copies the new firmware into MCU flash (address 0x8000000) and resets the micro.

Everything is OK except the process of firmware copy. Actually it takes a long time. For an average-sized bin file (10 KB) it may take 2 minutes to copy the firmware.

I have searched about this problem. Moving the copy function to SRAM is proposed as a solution. I performed this but nothing changed.

This function writes an array in MCU Flash:

```
progStatus Program(uint32_t start,uint32_t* Data, uint32_t size)
        {
        HAL_FLASH_Unlock();     
        for (uint32_t i=0;i<(size);i++)
                {
                if (HAL_FLASH_Program(FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_WORD, start, Data[i]) == HAL_OK)
                    {
                    start +=4;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        HAL_FLASH_Lock();
                        return PROG_ERROR;
                    }

        }
    HAL_FLASH_Lock();
    return PROG_OK; 
    }
```

The only way to program micro flash is by a single 32-bit aligned word at once. The following function is provided by ST.

```
HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_FLASH_Program(uint32_t TypeProgram, uint32_t Address, uint32_t Data)
{
  HAL_StatusTypeDef status = HAL_ERROR;
  
  /* Process Locked */
  __HAL_LOCK(&pFlash);

  /* Check the parameters */
  assert_param(IS_FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM(TypeProgram));
  assert_param(IS_FLASH_PROGRAM_ADDRESS(Address));

  /* Wait for last operation to be completed */
  status = FLASH_WaitForLastOperation(FLASH_TIMEOUT_VALUE);
  
  if(status == HAL_OK)
  {
    /* Clean the error context */
    pFlash.ErrorCode = HAL_FLASH_ERROR_NONE;

    /*Program word (32-bit) at a specified address.*/
    *(__IO uint32_t *)Address = Data;

    /* Wait for last operation to be completed */
    status = FLASH_WaitForLastOperation(FLASH_TIMEOUT_VALUE);
  }

  /* Process Unlocked */
  __HAL_UNLOCK(&pFlash);

  return status;
}
```

Finally we read 256 bytes from external SPI flash, erase a sector and then program the internal flash:

```
                    read3=mx_read(&addr,data,sizeof(data));
                    for(q=0 ; q<256 ; q++)
                        {
                        crc2=crc32h(data[q],crc2);
                        }
                    
                        status=ReAlign(data,sizeof(data),Data1,sizeof(Data1));
                        erase_status1=ErasePages(start,1);
                        prog_status=Program(start,Data1,sizeof(Data1));
                        start+=0x100;
                        addr.page++;
                        q=0;
```

We profiled the entire code. Calculating CRC32 and external flash read are performed very fast. The only bottleneck is the internal flash programming functions.

Is there any solution to overcome this problem?

Comment: Did you write the bootloader yourself or are you using something pre-packaged?

Comment: This is of course *unanswerable* without the details of the copy operation such as the source code implementing it.  Perhaps your code is inefficient, moving only one word from external flash to internal at a time.  Perhaps your code for interacting with the external flash is slow and being operated inefficiently.  Perhaps you're logging a lot of debug messages through a UART at a low baud rate...

Comment: The erase operation is usually the longest piece of the pie. I would look at how many times the erase operation is performed.  If you can erase larger blocks, sectors or the whole page, then write all the data to that section, that would be much faster than simply erasing 255 bytes at  a time.

Comment: @brhans The main writing function is provided by ST.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks. I updated the question.

Comment: Your chip supports half page programming (perhaps full page, too) somehow you came to the mistake conclusion it does not, but it actually does.  Make sure your ram function is stand alone and not calling anything that is in flash.

Comment: @ChrisStratton About the half or full-page programming, I will search. Thanks.
About the RAM, I moved all data and functions to SRAM.